# bash subshells vs bash -c

Tags: bash, subshell

Bash subshells (cmd1;cmd2) whill run in a sub bash process, while it can access the variable not exported, how this can be? Meanwhile, bash -c structure can not access unexported variable but it also run in a new shell,so what's the difference?

```
x=1
(echo $x)
bash -c 'echo $x'
```

Comment: In `(echo $x)` the variable `x` is expanded and replaced with `1` by the shell  before running `echo` in a subshell. So the subshell runs the command `echo 1`, not the `echo $x`.

Comment: In `bash -c 'echo $x'`, the argument `echo $x` is passed literally, without expansion. Since `x` is not exported, `$x` expands to nothing in the subshell.

Answer (score 0):

Both subshell and `bash -c` contexts can access exported variables.  To export a variable, one declares the variable as exported (e.g., `declare -x VAR`) or specifically exports it (`export VAR`).  Your example, it seems, does not export `x`.

More of the parent context is inherited by subshells (e.g., `( ... )`), than are by specific command executions (e.g., `bash -c ...`).

For example, the following items are inherited by subshells:

- Current working directory; *e.g., as set with `cd`, `pushd`, and/or `popd`*
- Directory stack (`DIRSTACK`); *e.g., as affected by `cd`, `pushd`, `popd`*
- File creation mask; *e.g., as set with `umask`*
- File handles/descriptors; *e.g., initially and as affected by `exec` redirections*
- Settings; *e.g., as affected by `set`, `shopt`, and `alias`*
- Shell variables and functions; *e.g., as set with `declare` and `=`*
- Exported variables and functions; *e.g., as declared with `declare -x` or exported with `export`*
- Signal traps for `ERR`; *e.g., as set with `trap ... ERR`*
- Certain special shell parameters; *e.g., `PPID`*

For example, the following items are inherited by command executions (w. `bash -c`):

- Current working directory; *e.g., as set with `cd`, `pushd`, and/or `popd`*
- File creation mask; *e.g., as set with `umask`*
- File handles/descriptors; *e.g., initially and as affected by `exec` redirections*
- Exported variables and functions; *e.g., as declared with `declare -x` or exported with `export`*

For additional detail, check out the Bash manpage, starting with the COMMAND EXECUTION ENVIRONMENT section.

*Note: Each command in a pipeline executes in dedicated processes/subshells.  With `lastpipe` enabled, the final pipeline command may run within the outer shell process.*

*Note: Other than when a command list is fully backgrounded with a trailing `&`, command lists are executed within the current shell process.  When backgrounded, command lists are executed in a dedicated process/subshell.*

Answer (score -3):

1. Assume that I have written following line inside `$HOME/.bashrc` file using cygwin in Windows.

   ```
   export testing="testing$$"
   ```

   After this I do <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> => bash.exe

   ```
   $ echo $testing
   testing7853
   ```
2. I open "cmd.exe"

   Inside that command prompt, I type

   ```
   C:> bash.exe -c "echo [$testing]"
   []

   C:>
   ```

   Reason:

   When we execute bash.exe it'll execute `~/.bashrc` and other related dependent default profile files.
   If we execute `bash.exe -c "related command"` then `.bashrc` is not executed.

   We are informing bash to execute related command.
   If you need that environment variable available inside `bash.exe -c` execute:

   ```
   C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables
   ```

   Set your required environment variable.
   For example I set certs environment variable.

   ```
   C:>bash.exe -c "echo [$certs]"
   [C:\apache-tomcat\certs]
   ```

   When we execute bash.exe it is a process waiting for the user input to exit from that process.

   When we execute `bash.exe -c`, a process is created. It will execute required commands and exit from that process.

   ```
   C:\Windows\System32\tasklist.exe | grep bash
   ```

   The above command will display related output of running process.